# How can I remove my image css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
.imgleft{
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

... but I want to make my website responsive, so when my width is smaller than 650 I want my image gone.

I tried following code, but it doesn't work :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .imgleft{
        background-color: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: `background-color: none;` is not valid. If you want it gone, use `display: none;` instead.

Comment: `background-image: none` why would changing the `background-color` have any effect on the image?

Answer (score 1):

You are just removing the `background-color` of image, which won't hide it :)

Try with `display:none`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .imgleft{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of your `background-color` to none, while you are supposed to set the value of your `background-image` to none.

So, what you're trying to achieve, is this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .imgleft {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

(see [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f8m1jcnq/2/) for a demo)

If you don't want either any background-color or any background-image, you could also do this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .imgleft {
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

(see [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f8m1jcnq/1/) for a demo)

... or this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .imgleft {
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/))